# Spark Scala Flumeutill not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting the below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/spark/streaming/flume/FlumeUtils$
>           at SampleStream$.main(NetworkWordCount.scala:10)
>           at SampleStream.main(NetworkWordCount.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.FlumeUtils$
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)

i refer below link

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/streaming-flume-integration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to package spark-streaming-flume and its dependencies (except spark-core and spark-streaming which are provided by spark-submit) into the application JAR.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/streaming-flume-integration.html has a better description about deploying. You can use this doc as there is no API changes between 1.4 and 1.6.

Comment: how to pack spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10-1.4.1.jar with code while building using SBT

Comment: You can use `--packages` to run like this `./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-flume_2.10:1.6.1` and it will add them to the runtime classpath.

Comment: `spark-submit streamingApp.jar --class com.hexa.twtsteam.SampleStream --packages org.apache.spark-streaming-flume_2.10:1.4.1 ` Still getting error

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all libraries loaded in classpath.
Add this to build.sbt file: `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-flume_2.10" % "1.6.1"`

Comment: How are you running your application? spark-submit?
You need to make big fat JAR file. Use spark assembly plugin. Or add those JAR files to class path while submitting app.

Comment: `spark-submit flume_2.10-1.0.jar --class com.hexa.twtsteam.SampleStream --packages org.apache.spark-streaming-flume_2.10:1.4.1` this is the command i am using